# Auto-reload inline plugin changes in Grails 3

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, livereload, grails-3.0, multi-project

I'm using Intellij Idea 15 and Grails 3.0.9 and auto-reloading of main application is working without many problems, but I'm unable to make auto-reloading work for inline plugin (or multi project in gradle as it's called now I think).

Is there any way to force this behaviour or the only way is to stop and run again the main application?

Comment: This has always been the case with inline plugins for all versions of Grails. Including 3.x

Comment: I thought it worked in older versions when I had used it, but I guess I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: No worries. I can personally confirm it does not work on v1.2, v1.3.7, v2.4.2.

Comment: I have found gsps within grails 2 inline plugins update whilst on 3 it requires a restart

Comment: Grails 3 is build on spring-boot so maybe try a way described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html I wan't try this in grails application, but in other app build on top of spring-boot it is working like in documentation.